# Does EFT Pro Tool have Galaxy A54 availability?

Tags: samsung, frp

On the most recent update on the EFT Pro Tool (4.6.3), there are no options for the Samsung Galaxy A54. I thought I had come across a YouTube video of someone FRP unlocking an A54 with EFT, but I cannot find the video anymore.

If there is a version of EFT Pro Tool that has options for the Galaxy A54, what is it?

I also am curious to know if the "Oppo A54" is the same thing. I have full registration on EFT Pro and would love it if I could get this Galaxy A54 unlocked without paying for a new program.

Comment: When talking about third party apps or other software please always include a link to the play store or a different source where the app can be downloaded. because of localization app names can be totally different around the world.

Comment: The Oppo A54 is *not* the same as the Samsung Galaxy A54. The Oppo has a Qualcomm SoC, and the Samsung has one of Samsung's Exynos SoCs.